# Is there anyway to export mapBox map to PDF, PNG from web?

Tags: mapbox

We are using MapBox api for showing map in web. We would like to export the map into PDF or PNG including GeoJSON data from web. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Static Image API for that, but it would require you to add the GeoJSON to your map via Mapbox:

> Static maps are standalone images that can be displayed on web and mobile devices without the aid of a mapping library or API. A static map image uses the Mapbox {mapid} and looks like an embedded map without any interactivity or controls.

https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/static/

If that's not an option you could take a look the Leaflet.Image plugin:

> Export images out of Leaflet maps without a server component, by using Canvas and CORS.

https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image

Comment: Leaftlet-image is the thing I was looking for. Thankz :)